# Error with command go get -u command. Cannot get package

Tags: git, go, github, visual-studio-code

In visual studio code, in the terminal section, I am trying to run the following golang command:

`go get -u github.com/my_github_name/my_repo/my_package`

(I have replaced the real values with my_name and my_package and below with my_user_name)

And the response is :

```
Cloning into '/Users/my_user_name/go/src/github.com/my_github_name/my_repo'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
package github.com/my_github_name/my_repo/my_package: exit status 128
```

This is not the first time I run this command and it has worked previously.
I am not aware of having changed my environment neither.

It looks as though the command cannot authenticate with github because it does not present it with my github user name and password because I am not prompted to provide them.

Error says terminal promts disabled. Would there be a way to enable them? Would this fix the problem?

Your help on that matter would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem belongs to git not go get. is your repo private? If yes, try to make sure you have permission to get that but git command like add ssh key and use: git config --global --add url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"

Answer (score 1):

As commented, if the repository is private, or even if it is public but you have [2FA activated](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/configuring-two-factor-authentication), you would not be able to use your (cached) password.
Hence [the suggestion](http://p2.onmadsen.com/2019/04/06/git-error-could-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-terminal-prompts-disabled/) from Mads Madsen:

```
git config --global --add url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

But check also your `git config credential.helper`: the wrong credential might be cached (for instance: the right password, which would not work if you have 2FA set up with your account)

Comment: Hi VonC, thank you for your help! Moving to SSH has actually fixed my problem.